# Why aren't my photos appearing in Google Photos?

Tags: google-photos

I've enabled the "Google Drive" setting in Photos, so I get a "Google Photos" folder in the root of my Google Drive. In this folder I can see all my current Google Photos that it imported from Google Plus.

I've copied 30GB of photos into this folder. It's finished syncing. I made sure they all had correct file dates, and exif dates.

None of them show up in Google Photos on Android or in the browser. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do they show up in Drive via the browser? I've seen no indication that Drive's Google Photos folder syncs BACK to Google Photos yet. Right now it's focused on bringing in photos FROM Google Photos.

Comment: Yes the files show up in Google Drive in the browser...

Comment: In https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6156103 it says "You'll see your Google Drive photos and videos in the "Photos" section of the Google Photos app"... Don't you think that means I should be able to see them in the app?

Comment: Not necessarily, no. They're different functions. That refers to the fact that, for quite some time now, adding photos to anywhere in Drive will allow them to appear in Photos. The new Google Photos folder is a different function entirely, and may not back-sync to Photos in the same way. From what I can tell, it's not a literal Drive folder at all, but merely a view of what's in your Google Photos. So it's more than likely a one-way connection. I just tested it myself, and found the same result. The file appears in Drive, but doesn't back-port to Photos.

Comment: I think they have it specifically designed to ignore this folder, otherwise it would cause a feedback loop with everything doubled. Since that folder displays the entire contents of Google Photos, for Google Photos to then scan it for photos and display them would double everything you have. And that's the issue: it's merely displaying the contents of Google Photos, not also storing them in a second location.